# Moving XAMPP folder to new computer

Tags: xampp

What are the most important files on Xampp folder that I need to copy from my old my Macbook pro to the new one. I'm confuse, cuz I backed up the whole Xammp file to my Icloud (bad& stupid idea i know) and I downloaded to the new mac. It's not working at all. It showed errors when I ran it or not complete project. I just need to know what folders on xampp file should I get if I wanted to past them to the new Xampp file?

thank u

I coied the whole xampp folder and pasted to new one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should just backup the files inside htdocs as those are your project files. When you download xampp in your new computer just place the file you backup into it. You might need to export your databases so you can just import it in your new computer.

These are just simple solutions that you can do. I believe there might be methods that are far more better than this.

Hope this helps you.